# Has anyone tested capedwarf (google appe engine equivalent) with gaelyk

Tags: google-app-engine, groovy, gaelyk, capedwarf

Anyone with stack who could be promising as far as I tested so far on GAE (+gaelyk)
and now with capedwarf (because of asset limitation on GAE).
Cheers,
Jim

Comment: hi, not yet. as they claim to be 100% compatible with App Engine there should be no problem. it looks like only thing is to point the `capedwarf.sh` script to your exploded webapp directory

Comment: Hello, tried today but with no luck, it appears that groovy files can be called and gtpl no beeing parsed, in capedwarf it is twisted regarding to the behavior of gae built in engine, any hints? (I tweaked appengine-web.xml and web.xml),

Comment: after inquiry it seems that capedwarf routing is biased, the left hand side of expression in routes.groovy always will be a groovy file and not a url (or part of) whereas the right hand (either a redirect or forward) is ok for a groovy file (not a template with extension `gtpl`). I will see if I can raise a feature ticket

Comment: Cool. I'm looking forward for any update. Can you share your test project on GitHub?

Comment: yes in fact it is the basic template from gaelyk, however I suppose it has to  do with the gaelyk jar artefact, my shame I sent an email to people of capedwarf :(

Comment: Hi again, that's me :) apparently the routes file never gets read on line 89 of http://pastebin.com/S06iu3Pp , for the moment I do not know if it has to do with capedwarf or gaelyk

Comment: finally I inspect the path regarding the war, when doing `new File("/")`, it doesn't restrict to the deployed war but to the whole system file, so I think it is more related to CapeDwarf :(

Comment: Hi: "la garde meurt mais ne se rend pas?" 8-), musketyr? ^^

Comment: Vraiment! I've opened the issue in Gaelyk  - https://github.com/gaelyk/gaelyk/issues/220 . You can place your routes in plugin instead - http://gaelyk.appspot.com/tutorial/plugins. Simply said - create a class extending groovyx.gaelyk.plugins.PluginBaseScript, copy the code from routes.groovy into it's run method and create a simple descriptor META-INF/services/groovyx.gaelyk.plugins.PluginBaseScript containing just the name of the class created.

Comment: hello all, any update about the concern?regards, JM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some news

The first answer of musketyr was right (`capedwarf.sh/bat` + path of exploded app).
However path of exploded app structure should be:

1. App artefacts (WEB-INF, CSS, images...)
2. A directory name with the same name of app with the same content
   as (1)

Comment: currently not able to serve .gtpl files, waiting for feedback from other users